# Slickgrid checkbox row selection not working

Tags: javascript, slickgrid

*** SOLVED see my comment below ***

I am trying to implement checkbox row selection model by following this example in slickgrid http://mleibman.github.io/SlickGrid/examples/example-checkbox-row-select.html but its not working.

When I try it in my application all I get is a checkbox in the header cell but all the rows have a "..." (value undefined).

Can someone help please?

Here is my code :

```
 var EntityGrid = function ($container, el, columns, collection, filterFields, isUnmappable, source) {

    var options = {
        enableCellNavigation:true,
        enableColumnReorder:false,
       // forceFitColumns:true,
        enableTextSelectionOnCells:true,
        rowHeight: 28
    };

    var checkboxSelector = new Slick.CheckboxSelectColumn({
        cssClass: "slick-cell-checkboxsel"
    });

    this.isUnmappable = isUnmappable;
    this.source = source;
    columns = this.prepareColumns(columns, checkboxSelector);
    this.collection = collection;
    this.$container = $container;
    this.dataView = new Slick.Data.DataView();
    this.grid = new Slick.Grid(el, this.dataView, columns, options);
    this.grid.setSelectionModel(new Slick.RowSelectionModel({selectActiveRow: false}));
    this.grid.registerPlugin(checkboxSelector);
    this.filterFields = filterFields;
    this.setupGridEvents();
    this.setupFilter();
    this.grid.render();
    var columnpicker = new Slick.Controls.ColumnPicker(columns, this.grid, options);
    return this;
};

EntityGrid.prototype = {

    prepareColumns:function (columns, checkboxSelector) {
        var self = this;
        columns.push(checkboxSelector.getColumnDefinition());
        _.each(columns, function (item) {
            if (item.type === "link") {
                item.formatter = self.linkFormatter;
            } else if (item.type === "editableBoolean") {
                item.formatter = self.checkboxFormatter;
            } else {
                item.formatter = self.defaultFormatter;
            }
        });
... other columns definations
```

Comment: Ok I had a default formatter which was the root cause of this issue. Once I turn the default formatter off the row selection checkbox works fine.

Comment: Would you be able to post what you did to fix it as a response to this question, and mark it as an answer? It's generally considered good form to include an answer for others who may have come across the question, say, from internet searches.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All I did to get it working is to stop my default formatter from being applied to the check-box select column.

I added a condition in the _.each loop as shown below :

```
_.each(columns, function (item) {
        if(item.cssClass !== "slick-cell-checkboxsel") {
            if (item.type === "link") {
                item.formatter = self.linkFormatter;
            } else if (item.type === "editableBoolean") {
                item.formatter = self.checkboxFormatter;
            } else {
                item.formatter = self.defaultFormatter;
            }
        }
    });
```